# What does the NTP daemon do on startup vs. restart?

Tags: time, synchronization, ntp

I'm using Rapsberry Pies and need them to keep time as well as possible without using a RTC. They are doing quite a good job, as long as they're online. Even when they're offline, they manage quite well between Internet connections. My problem, however, is that those few times when their "clock" does drift, it takes too long for it to get back on track. I know the NTP daemon has advanced algorithms to speed up and slow down time safely until it's on the right track, but it doesn't do it for me.

The only solution I could come up with that immediately corrected the time when it was way off, was this:

```
            service ntp stop
            ntpdate 0.se.pool.ntp.org
            service ntp start
```

First I tried simply restarting the NTP service, but it didn't help. However, if I reboot the computer it does sync the time.

**Questions:**

Do I really need ntpdate in this case? 
Can I tell the ntp daemon to be more aggressive in syncing the time?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to ntp.conf

```
tinker panic 0
```

or add `-g` to the ntpd startup options.